# VS2015RC MVC project upgrade from beta4 to beta5

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS2015RC and was trying to upgrade a basic MVC VNEXT project from beta4 to beta5 and the project (just an empty shell created by VS) has a dependency on CommandLineUtils.Sources that it cant resolve.

Unable to locate Microsoft.Framework.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-beta5

The DNVM upgraded just fine. (.NET Version Manager v1.0.0-beta6-10395)

Project.Lock.Json file has the dependency

"Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration.Core/1.0.0-beta5": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.Framework.CommandLineUtils.Sources": "1.0.0-beta5",

Did I miss a step?  Ideas???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now pushed Microsoft.Framework.CommandLineUtils.Sources.1.0.0-beta5 to nuget.org. This should unblock folks. We will remove this dependency from the impacted packages in Beta 6.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended workaround for Visual Studio RC users is who are working from a "Web Site" template is:

- Remove "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5" from project.json
- Remove gen command from project.json

In the next release of Visual Studio, we do not have this dependency (or the gen command) in the web application template anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with
"Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",

so currently I've just changed it back to beta4. Also I've opened ticket on
https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2163